# Does $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}y(x)$ exist for this nonlinear ode?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the (very) nonlinear IVP

$
 f(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       y'=\displaystyle\frac{(1+x^2)y}{(1+x^2+y^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}} \\
       y(0)=\eta
     \end{array}
   \right.
$

Where $\eta \in \mathbb{R}$. I've already shown the a local solution exists in a neigborhood around the origin, what is left to show (or not show), is that

$\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} y(x)=\infty$ for any initial condition $\eta \neq 0$

What I have tried so far was to construct upper and lower solutions to show that $y(x)$ is bounded by two unbounded functions independent of $\eta$. While I did find an upper solution, this isn't enough. Finding a lower solution didn't seem very easy as I wasn't able to estimate $y'$ from below. From this work, I was able to show

$$\eta < y(x) < \eta \exp{\left[\frac{3x+x^3}{3(1+\eta^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\right]}$$

What I wanted to sort of reason also was that we know, for $\eta >0$, that $y(x)> \eta$ because $y'(x)>0$ for all $x>0$. From here, we can also conclude that $\displaystyle\lim_{x->\infty} y'(x) = \infty$. Hence $y(x)$ is an increasing function with unbounded derivative, so that it must go to infinity as $x$ does. I've got a feeling that this cannot play out though, so I'm not sure in what direction I should be going in from here.

EDIT: Just a small one, notice that for $\eta = 0$, $y(x)=0$ for all $x$, so it's best to consider $\eta>0$, as it'll be the same argument for the negative case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $y = 0$ is a solution, so your desired conclusion is certainly wrong.  The most you can hope for is $y \to +\infty$ when $\eta > 0$ and 
$y \to -\infty$ when $\eta < 0$.

EDIT: You can use Grönwall's Inequality to prove global existence of solutions.  When $y > 0$, $y$ is increasing.  If it had a finite limit $Y$ as $x \to \infty$, you'd need $y' \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$ with $y \to Y$, but that is not the case.  Thus if $\eta > 0$ we must have $\lim_{x \to \infty} y = +\infty$.  By symmetry, if $\eta < 0$ we have $\lim_{x \to \infty} y = -\infty$.

Comment: Yes, I think I noticed this at the same time you did, haha. The interesting case is going to be when $\eta \neq 0$